# Scheduled event displayed in room info box, clicking on it gets you to the cat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, events

When I look at the [C++ chat room's scheduled events tab](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/10/loungec?tab=schedule), it shows one current event. (The event itself is silly, it was just someone playing with this feature.) That event is also shown in the room's info box (whatever that's called officially), right above the users currently in the room.

Clicking on the link in the room info box, however, gets you to the [cat which messed up SO ("Oops! Something Bad Happened!")](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/rooms/info/10/Lounge%3CC++%3E). The same is true from all other places I could find where that link is accessible, for example the [list of rooms with a current event](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms?tab=favorite&sort=event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sent the cat away from your room.

<sub>*Queue some bad joke about cats and C++; unfortunately I couldn't come up with a good one.*</sub>